# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException on spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, smtp

The spring boot app should send an email after the registration to the user.
When I test the registration with postman, I got this error message..

> "message": "Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 1025;\n  nested exception is:\n\tjavax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 1025;\n  nested exception is:\n\tjavax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake"
> **

As mail server I use mailDev in a docker container. The container terminal logs these messages:

MailDev webapp running at http://0.0.0.0:80

MailDev SMTP Server running at 0.0.0.0:25

The Logs sound fine, but despite this I have no access to the web app of the mail-server (I use a MacBook). Is there maybe a fault at the mail server?

The app is running with this properties..

```yaml
server:
  error:
    include-message: always
    include-binding-errors: always
spring:
  datasource:
    password: password
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: postgres
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    show-sql: true
  mail:
    host: localhost
    port: 1025
    username: hello
    password: hello
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          socketFactory:
            class: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
            fallback: false
            port: 1025
          ssl:
            enable: true
```

The project is public under my GitHub profile
https://github.com/farmerWhoCode/TrainingBooking

I find some hints here at stackoverflow, that point out wrong properties in my application.yml file. But nothing helps me to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried using the terminal to check the Mail server is accessible?  Have you exposed the Mail servers port in the docker container to allow it to be accessible?

Comment: Having said the above have you tried disabling ssl in your app (and possible the mail server)?

Comment: According to https://github.com/maildev/maildev, unless you configure SSL for http and smtp, maildev just runs without SSL (like lots of other services). So you either have to configure maildev for SSL, or configure your client (i.e. the spring boot app) to use plain connections.  Otherwise there will be no successful handshake, as the error also indicates!